# Reflection - getInterfaces() shows weird interfaces

Tags: java, hibernate, reflection

Using `Hibernate`, I get a `List<BlablaPO>` (`BlablaPO` implements `Blabla`).
When I do something like this:

```
for(Blabla blabla : list) {
    Class<?>[] interfazes = blabla.getClass().getInterfaces();
}
```

This code is just a part of a piece of code that accepts a `Collection<T>`. Today, I used this code again on a new `List<Blabla>`, my returned interfaces do no have Blabla in them, instead I get 2 interfaces:

- interface `org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy`
- interface `javassist.util.proxy.ProxyObject`

Am I loading the collection wrongly? I tried loading the collection eagerly.

EDIT: 
I am fairly sertain that the problem is because I have my collection loaded lazyly.

Comment: `blabla.getClass()` is the problem, (`blabla` is not `new BlablaPO()`), try `org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxyHelper#getClassWithoutInitializingProxy(blabl‌​a).getInterfaces()`.

Comment: That is not the problem. In case, if BlablaPO implements Blabla, then blabla is BlablaPO. The problem was that I had loaded everything lazily.

Comment: blabla is a BlablaPO but not exactly a new BlablaPO(), in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because Hibernate replaces your instances with generated classes that proxy for your own classes. For example, a bean like:

```
class Foo implements SomeInterface {
   @OneToMany
   public List<MyBean> getBar() { ... }
}
```

will be subclassed by Hibernate similarly to the following class:

```
class Foo$Hibernate extends Foo implements HibernateProxy, ProxyObject {
  @Override
  public String getBar() { Hibernate.loadFromDBOnDemand(); }
}
```

When you ask for the interfaces of `Foo$Hibernate`, you will not be able to see `SomeInterface`, you have to first navigate up to `SomeInterface`. The condition `foo instanceOf SomeInterface` will however continue to hold and might be what you want to go for.

Comment: So, what can be done to solve this problem? Shouldn't the interfaces of the superclass also be shown?

Comment: You have to iterate down the class hierarchy. You could check a class to implement HibernateProxy and in this case, instead of checking the class itself, you check the super class for the interface.

Comment: That is true, but in a later stage, all my values of my object would be empty since I received it lazily loaded.

Comment: No, the Hibernate features are still available, you cannot avoid virtual dispatch using reflection. You merely access the type graph for analytics.

Comment: What I mean is, I got into this situation because I loaded everything lazily. As soon as I got that fixed, everything worked just prefectly fine :). Thanks for your insight though!

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I loaded everything lazily. The solution was to load everything correctly, which resulted in the code working 100% perfectly :).

Comment: Loading lazily is not loading incorrectly. It's the default behavior and sometimes more desirable than eager loading.

Comment: I know it's not bad. In fact, I try to load everything lazy always for minimum load. In this case, I needed the whole object, not just the id.